# What does BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT do behind the scenes?

Tags: c++, boost

Trying to understand where the scope exit blocks would execute with respect to automatic variables' deallocations, I wrote this program:

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A's constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A's destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
  public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B's constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "B's destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT()
    {
        std::cout << "Scope exit 1" << std::endl;
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
    B b;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT()
    {
        std::cout << "Scope exit 2" << std::endl;
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
A's constructor
B's constructor

Scope exit 2
B's destructor
Scope exit 1
A's destructor
```

There is a common order among automatic variables and scope exit blocks. I am wondering how does boost achieve this? Does the BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT macro create an object on the stack whose destructor executes the exit block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right about your suspicion. It creates an object whose destructor executes the block. From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT.html):

> Warning: The implementation executes the scope exit body within a destructor thus the scope exit body must never throw in order to comply with STL exception safety requirements.

As a side note, in C++11 I would personally prefer a helper class based on [the scope guard idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Scope_Guard) that executes a lambda function to the boost macros. This seems a lot cleaner to me, and probably would make it easier to spot what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT indeed ends up creating a local variable whose destructor contains your code. Destructors are executed in reverse construction order, hence your exit handlers will be executed bottom-up, with other objects destruction interleaved.